# Perforce change commit username and date

Tags: bash, perforce

I have [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com) project with history and I want to change username and date in some commits.
How can I change in submitted commit username and date Perforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'p4 change -f' to update submitted changelists. The command requires that you have the appropriate privilege (admin or super). See: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_change.html

Comment: Thanks
If I have this rights, what exactly I should write p4 change -f ... ?

Comment: For example, 'p4 change -f 12479' will bring up your editor with the changelist spec for change 12479, and will allow you to update the username, change description, etc.

Comment: Can I do it in bash script ?

Comment: Yes, you can combine the '-f' and '-i' flags in 'p4 change -f -i', in which case you provide the new changelist data as stdin, as in: (1) prepare file 'change.txt', then (2) 'cat change.txt | p4 change -f -i'